# Solve this limit (Maclaurin or differentiate?)

Tags: limits, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I have this assignment where I should calculate the limit below:
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin 2x}{x\cos x} $$ I can use l'Hospitals rule (because it is a "zero divided by zero"-case) and therefore differentiate: $$ f(x) = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin 2x}{x\cos x} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{x\cos x} $$
$$ f'(x) = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{2(\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x)}{-\sin x} $$ I don't know if this is the right way to go, if there is, I need to extract this more because $\sin(0)=0$.

Option number two is to use Maclaurin:
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{x\cos x} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{2(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+O(x^7))(1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+O(x^6))}{x(1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+O(x^6))}$$
Am I on the right way in some case above?
And If I am, how do I handle O-notations?

Comment: $\sin (2x) = 2\sin x\cos x$.

Comment: If you already had $\;\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{x\cos x}\;$ , why in the world didn't you cancel the cosines?? And after that, the derivative is wrong...

Comment: I don't understand why would anywone downvote this question: the OP is showing some self work! He may be wrong, but that's not what downvotes are for, imo.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I don't know, that solution was too easy!

Comment: @DonAntonio Write your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted!

Comment: I already did write an answer long time ago, @theva ...:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin 2x}{x\cos x}=\frac{\sin 2x}{2x}\cdot\frac2{\cos x}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use the equivalence
$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\sin 2x\over 2x}=1.$$

Comment: Is $ x\cos x = 2x $?

Comment: Isn't. Multiply and divide by $2x$ and use the equivalence.